# Why can't res.sendFile access __dirname + "/../public" if the script calling the function isn't the main app .js file

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following folder structure:

```
public/
   bug-reporter/
      bugs.html
src/
   bug-reporter.js
app.js
```

If I do this from app.js, it works fine:

```
// app.js
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/bug-reporter/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/bug-reporter/bugs.html')
```

But if do this:

```
// app.js
const bugReporter = require('./src/bug-reporter')
app.get('/bug-reporter/', bugReporter.home)

// bug-reporter.js
exports.home = ((req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/../public/bug-reporter/bugs.html'))
```

In the console I get error `ForbiddenError: Forbidden`.

Comment: What does this `/../` is supposed to do?

Comment: Look at the folder structure

Comment: Why would you change the path in the first place when you use `__dirname` which is relative to the project root?

Comment: There is no such thing as `/../` inside an absolute path

Comment: If I don't use it I get `no such file or directory` and I can see it looking in the wrong folder. It doesn't seem like __dirname is the project root, but rather the file's path, which is different.

Comment: So what path should I use, given the folder structure above?

Comment: You were right `__dirname` doesn't show root dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `path.resolve`

```
exports.home = ((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/bug-reporter/bugs.html')))
```

Because `..` is not allowed in absolute paths